# android audio recording - Timing issue

Tags: android, audio

im recording something and i wanna know the EXACT time the thing i recorded happened.

for example, i make a start record command (adjusting to 1 sec record for example), then i read the data into a buffer using the read command. then i process the data using FFT on mini chunks of the main buffer, and find out where in the buffer is the frequency i was waiting for. now i want to know WHEN exactly was that freq played in real life.

i hope u can understand my question.. 
thanks,

Ofer.

Comment: Exact with reference to what?  How do you plan to synchronize the clock in the app to any clock outside the app?

Comment: thanks for your reply, Exact with reference to his own timer. if his date.getTime() is 214555353ms when the sound reached the microphone, i wanna know that time..

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?